# Formik ErrorMessage not appearing on browser

Tags: reactjs, formik

In this simple form, I take description and category(select) from user inputs.
I try to display error by rendering prior, and it worked completely fine.

When I reafactored, using ErrorMessage from formik, it stopped showing error message on the browser.

I read the coumentation, and there seems no issue regarding my code below.
Any suggestion or something I didn't notice?

```
const initialValues = {
    description: '',
    category: '',
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    description: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    category: Yup.string().required('Required'),
});

const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Form data', values);
};

const AddForm = () => {
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            ValidationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
            <Form className='container'>
                <div className='form-control'>
                    <label htmlFor='description'></label>
                    <Field
                        type='text'
                        id='description'
                        name='description'
                        placeholder='Enter Description...'
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage name='description' />
                </div>

                <div className='form-control'>
                    <label htmlFor='category'></label>
                    <Field name='category' as='select'>
                        <option value='' label='Select Category' />
                        <option value='home' label='Home' />
                        <option value='work' label='Work' />
                        <option value='entertainment' label='Entertainment' />
                    </Field>
                        <ErrorMessage name='category' />
                </div>

                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </Form>
        </Formik>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because you mistyped `validationSchema` to `ValidationSchema` i.e

```
<Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
```

Here is demo working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-field-ieip1?file=/src/App.js